# How can I add something like logcat which have all errror information in it?

Tags: android, exception

Please tell me how I can add a file in my application which will store all the error messages that occur during an application life cycle. Tell me any solution immediately?  Like in my application I want a button. When clicked it will show all the error messages that occured
during run time when I started application, such as "connection not found", etc. All errors should be stored there and on click it should displayed.

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Comment: thelper           i accept that

Answer (score 0):

The log you want to see on button click  is in itself a new application. You should download **application alogcat (alogCat.apk)**  . You will get it on internet. It shows all the logs throughout your app and you can send that log to your email id . But if you want to see that logs on button click in your app you have to make that app.

Comment: can you please tell me something that how to work with alogCat.apk

Comment: @ravi you just install it and you will see the Logs in the screen.Suppose you launch your application and a force close appears then you can go to alogcat and can see what was error in red text. You can also create filter based on your logs in your app.You can download the apk from http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/downloads/detail?name=alogcat-2.3.apk

Answer (score 0):

otherwise we can print all the errors to a file and on click of log button we can read from that file.
like in our program in try catch we are printing some error message so instead of printing that message we can write those message to a file and on clicking of log button we can read and display those message to user.